# Instragram's UUID Creation Failing

Tags: postgresql, guid, uuid, instagram

I'm trying to implement Instagram's UUID that they talked about in this post: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

My implementation looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION engagement.next_id(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
    seq_id bigint;
    now_millis bigint;
    shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('engagement.table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;

    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
    result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
    result := result | (shard_id << 10);
    result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: relation "engagement.table_id_seq" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT nextval('engagement.table_id_seq') %% 1024 ^ QUERY: SELECT nextval('engagement.table_id_seq') %% 1024 CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function next_id() line 8
```

Am I actually suppose to create a table called table_id_seq or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the sequence

```
create sequence engagement.table_id_seq
```

If you don't have the Instagram's 64 bits uuid size constraint you can use the much simpler postgresql's `uuid_generate_v1mc()`. The postgresql `uuid` type is 128 bits long.

```
create table t (id serial, uid uuid);

insert into t (uid)
select uuid_generate_v1mc()
from generate_series(1, 100000);
```

It is sortable by creation time:

```
select *
from (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(order by uid) rn
    from t
    order by id
) s
where id != rn;
```

Comment: Why did Instangram have a size constraint - is it something to do with if they had larger UID's then the database queries would not have run fast enough?